# Is there a list of common English verbs with all of the inflectional "principal parts"?

Tags: english, reference-request, verbs, lexicon, frequency

I am looking for a list of common English verbs (1000 to 2000 most-frequent) which gives the distinct inflectional forms (spelled: pronunciation is irrelevant). For example, "sits, sit, sat, sat, sitting", "eats, eat, ate, eaten, eating". The purpose of the list is to serve as a component of a verb-generating program in another language. I don't want to have to devise orthographic rules to convert /sit+ing/ into [sitting] and manually typing a list is something I want to avoid. Does such a list already exist?

Comment: It should by possible to extract the list of verb forms from wiktionary and match it against a frequency list (or use the frequency list as a seed for extraction) ... still some amount of work to invest.

Comment: Well, that kind of coding is above my pay grade, which is why I'm looking for an actual list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea of the frequency, but [here is a downloadable list of 1,000 verbs with each of the five forms from the Bangladesh University of Business and Technology](https://www.studocu.com/row/document/bangladesh-university-of-business-and-technology/english/1000-english-verbs-forms-with-v1-v2-v3-v4-v5/21839792)

Comment: I do wonder what happened to number 856…

Comment: @Draconis - I guess between "state" and "stay" there should have been "stave, staved/stove, staved/stove/stoven, staves, staving" where they couldn't decide which of the alternative forms to use. Or maybe they failed to decide which of the verbs "station", "statue", or "stave" fits their list better.